# PHP:!empty(array) returns true?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which returns like this:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'casualty_charge' => null
      'count' => string '0' (length=1)
```

Now How can I evaluate this array to false where key values for `casualty_charge is`Null`or`count`is`0`

Comment: you want that if you itrate this array and index is 0 then it should say false? otherwise true.

Comment: Create a function, iterate the array, job done.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh - No when key value for `casualty_charge=Null` or `count = 0` I want to evaluate it to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through you array to validate your condition:

```
function false_check($array){
   foreach ($array as $v)
       if(!isset$v['casualty_charge'] or !$v['count']) return false;
}
```